# CSS select input inside form element

Tags: html, css

I have an input field inside a from element and when the input is selected I want to to display the ul element.

css looks like this:

```
.ulclass {
  background: #f0a;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

form input.inputclass:focus + ul.ulclass {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jwc4g156/

I'm able to do this without the form tags, but I can't seem to select it when the input field is within the form tags. Can a css wizard please help me?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot do it. Consider `:focus-within` on form instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406959/8620333

Comment: Thanks Temani, this answered my question!